# How to refresh the dataset in Power BI which was imported from a Power BI (M-Query)

Tags: powerbi, visualization, powerquery, kql

I am trying to visualize the logs dataset in Power BI which I got from Aure Logs with the help of Kusto Query Language (KQL). I have exported the output of the logs to an M-Query and with the help of that M-Query, I have imported the dataset to Power BI.

Now I want to refresh my dataset on the interval of 2 hours. How can I do it without manual intervention? Please help me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You simply [Configure Scheduled Refresh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/refresh-scheduled-refresh) in the Power BI Service.

You can also query the logs in real-time using [Azure Data Explorer to query Log Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/query-monitor-data) as a DirectQuery source.